# How to get the first number in input values of range number or undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to get the first number value out of values with number or undefined range.

Obviously this fails for 0 which is falsy. What is the logical expression to return this?

```
    type Nomber = number | undefined

    function a_or_b_or_c_number_value_including_zero(a: Nomber, b: Nomber, c: Nomber) {
      return (a || b || c)
    }

    const test = (a: Nomber, b: Nomber, c: Nomber, expected: any) => {
      let got = a_or_b_or_c_number_value_including_zero(a, b, c)
      if (got !== expected) {
        console.log([a, b, c], 'fail', got, expected)
      }
    }


test(1, 2, 3, 1)
test(undefined, 1, 2, 1)
test(0, 1, 2, 0)
test(undefined, 0, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but maybe the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) serves your needs

Comment: wow that worked, let me accept that as an answer if you put it.

Comment: Glad it worked, I just posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [*nullish coalescing operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to check it.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

> The **nullish coalescing operator (`??`)** is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) or [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

---

This can be used in your code like below.

```js
function a_or_b_or_c_number_value_including_zero(a: Nomber, b: Nomber, c: Nomber) {
  return (a ?? b ?? c); // Modified
}
```

This will make the code work the way you want, which will not make `0` equal to `false`.

---

This is how the code works.

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `a ??` | If `a` isn't `null` or `undefined`, use `a`. |
| `b ?? c` | If `b` is `null` or `undefined`, use `c`, else, use `b`. |

---

In conclusion, the nullish coalescing operator is a useful feature to not make `0` and `""` equal to `false` (while `||` evaluates those values to `false`).

Answer (score 1):

Use [??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead of `||`

```
function a_or_b_or_c_number_value_including_zero(a: Nomber, b: Nomber, c: Nomber) {
      return (a ?? b ?? c)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to workaround the 0 failing for being falsy.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in order to write a function that accept any number of values and returns the first not `undefined` one:

```
type Nomber = number | undefined

function getFirstNumber(...values: Nomber[]) {
  for(let value of values){
    if (value !== undefined) return value;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

You can see a [demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gWwEYQE5QLxQHYFdlpQA%20Uu2AJhAGYCW2E5AUI1WQMbA1zZQDmEwAGI1UAZ2Ax8KVAAoAdAoBuAQwA2uCKIBcsRNIDaAXQCUUAN6MoUKnFmqBUFeuhwqjtRtHGLVqzTcyThpQAIQYWGSUtPTkpqgCuKg8QRAA3JZQAL4Z8cCJPJHUdAzp2YwA9OVQAOq2ANaiUADuNMAAFjhwUGDKqMoIENjAaKKMbNyicPZyqnC8MvxCIuKSBLLGxhVVtagNza0dytggOFKErt29-QIjYxNTEDNzCwLCYhJnsoXRDAA0UABGf4AJg2Wxq9UaLXaUAADHdsJNprN5os3itPjJvsVyP9YRsgA).

Comment: What's a demo hero?

Comment: @connexo I think it's a spelling mistake. I think it means _"Demo here"_.

Comment: yeah lol, editing

Answer (score 0):

Use rest parameter spread with `Array.find`, along with a nullish coalescing operator that will return `false` if no match is found.

```js
const test = (...args) => args.find(v => v !== undefined) ?? false

console.log(test(1, 2, 3, 1))
console.log(test(undefined, 1, 2, 1))
console.log(test(0, 1, 2, 0))
console.log(test(undefined, 0, 2, 0))
console.log(test())
```